# Ionic - Select-searchable not displaying any items

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I’m using the Ionic select-searchable plugin as I have a massive list of brands that a user can search through. My code at the moment looks like this:

TS code

```js
// Brand
brandList: Brand[] = [];
selectedBrandModel: Brand;

this.http.get(this.singleton.URL_GET_BRANDS, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    for(let tempBrand of data) {
      for(let tempSubBrand of tempBrand.Brands) {
        this.brandList.push({id: tempSubBrand.id, name: tempSubBrand.name});
        console.log("CREATED ID: " + tempSubBrand.id + " W NAME " + tempSubBrand.name);
      }
    }

    console.log(this.brandList);
  }, err => {

  }, () => {
    // this.selectCondition();
});
```

HTML

```html
<ion-item style="margin-top: 10px">
    <select-searchable
      #productBrand
      title="Brand"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedBrandModel"
      [items]="brandList"
      itemValueField="id"
      itemTextField="name"
      [canSearch]="true"
      (onChange)="change($event)"
    >
    </select-searchable>
  </ion-item>
```

All followed from the documentation, however, the list just returns empty. Does anyone have any clues as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - items is undefined at the time when select-searchable is being initialized, and suspecting a timing issue, I added an *ngIf to ensure the searchable is initialized only if the list is loaded. For me, it resolved the issue:

```
<ion-item style="margin-top: 10px">
<select-searchable *ngIf="brandList"
  #productBrand
  title="Brand"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedBrandModel"
  [items]="brandList"
  itemValueField="id"
  itemTextField="name"
  [canSearch]="true"
  (onChange)="change($event)"
>
</select-searchable>
```